# Determine the lines, circles, triangles or rectangles in a matrix

Tags: algorithm

I have a matrix and it can include lines, circles, triangles or rectangles. I need to find out which one and find the bigger one for example if there is a rectangle the answer should be a rectangle istead of line.

Do you have any idea how to create that algorithm and how to implement that?

Thank you

Comment: What does it even mean for a matrix to include a shape?

Comment: I mean there is a matrix full of 0s and 1s ...1s together form a shape

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Use hough transform to find any customized shape in matrix which can be considered as binary image.

[Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform)